# ToolTip style on TextBoxStyle {WPF}

Tags: wpf, styles

I try apply tooltip style on textboxstyle In user control. Style I have in:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

 <!--Style definition-->

</UserControl.Resources>
```

ToolTipStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="ToolTipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>           
</Style>
```

TextBoxStyle:

```
    <Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

        <!--Apply toolip style-->
        <Setter Property="ToolTip.Style" Value="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}"/>


        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Path =(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

TextBoxStyle apply on textbox constrol:

```
    <TextBox Name="tbNick" 
             Text="{Binding Nick, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
             Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}"/>
```

I get this compile error:

> {"Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the
>   object to which it applies."}

StackTrace:

> at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e,
>   IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    at Spirit.Views.ShellView.InitializeComponent() in
>   c:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\C#\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_MEF\Views\ShellView.xaml:line
>   1    at Spirit.Views.ShellView..ctor() in
>   C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\C#\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_MEF\Views\ShellView.xaml.cs:line
>   9

Apply tooltip style on textbox style is not allowed in WPF? What I do wrong?

Also in WPF I use caliburn.micro and MEF, but I think it doesn’t caused this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.
You may have to check here [http://windows-presentation-foundation.com/WPF_Triggers.aspx](http://windows-presentation-foundation.com/WPF_Triggers.aspx#avalon-CHP-5-EX-25)

check this code for setting tooltip style

```
<Grid>

  <Grid.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MyTooltip" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">

      <Setter Property = "HorizontalOffset" Value="50"/>

      <Setter Property = "VerticalOffset" Value="50"/>

      <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Orange"/>

      <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="Red"/>

      <Setter Property = "FontSize" Value="14"/>

      <Setter Property = "FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

      <Setter Property = "FontFamily" Value="Courier New"/>

    </Style>

  </Grid.Resources>



  <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="20">

    Pass over with your Mouse

    <TextBox.ToolTip>

      <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource MyTooltip}">

        <TextBlock>This is the Tooltip</TextBlock>

      </ToolTip>

    </TextBox.ToolTip>

  </TextBox>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no such attached property as `ToolTip.Style`, and compiler gives not quite informative description of the error. If you want to have a custom style for the `TextBox` use implicit style:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Style.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
               <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
               <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            </Style>
         </Style.Resources>
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
               <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <TextBox Name="tbNick" Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}" Text="Test" ToolTip="Hey"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```